# Confusing "converts an array of numeric characters to an int value" behavior

Tags: java

"converts an array of **numeric characters** to an int value."

Here is the code:

```
public static int parseInt(char[] a){
    int result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        result=result*10+(a[i]-'0');
    }
    return result;
}
```

My  question is: why we need `-'0'` in this method?

Second question is:  What if it is not numeric characters, e.g. if it is just array of characters, such as `char[] a={'a'，'b'，'c'，'d'，'e'}`?

How can I adjust the code to convert it to numeric value?

Comment: the second part of the question is so absurd that I almost chuckled myself to death. "How can I adjust the code to convert [alphabetic characters] to numeric values?" - well, as soon as you can tell me how many sheep is `zzz` sheep, you can be sure I'll be the first to answer...

Answer (score 1):

Characters '0' to '9' are equivalent to int values 48 to 57, so to get the value represented by a char, you must subtract 48 to it.

For your second question, what would mean converting 'a' into a numeric value ?

Comment: if a={'1','2','5'} when I call a[0] is a int value, which is 49, so we need to subtract '0' which is 48? why we can directly get int value when we call a[0]?

Comment: Because a char is not an int even if there is a natural conversion between those two types... Look at that and you should get it : http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

You question is more interesting than it looks at first sight. Common humans use base 10 numbers and in any know charset numbers from 0 to 9 have consecutive values. So the value of 'x' where 'x' is a char from '0' to '9' is 'x' - '0'.

But mathematicians use number in arbitrary base. Base 2 (binary), 8 (octal) and 16 (hexadecimal) are current for informaticians, but base 12 (and its derivative 60) is indirectly used in hour, minutes and seconds. Older monetary systems used partially base 12, because a division by 2, 3, or 4 is exact.

And Java acknowledge these arbitrary bases through `Character.getNumericValue(char c)` that gives :

- 'x' - '0' for character '0' to '9'
- 'x' - 'a' + 10 for characters 'a' to 'z' (including derivatives : 'é' is same as 'e')
- 'X' - 'A' + 10 for characters 'A' to 'Z' (including upper case derivatives)

So the generalization of you function for a larger number of characters would be :

```
public static int parseInt(char[] a){
    int result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        result=result*base+(Character.getNumericValue(a[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And you can control that it gives correct result in hexadecimal for `char[] a={'a'，'b'，'c'，'d'，'e', 'f'}` with base = 16.